# Signalr .net client in a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a problem with the .net client in a windows service. After some time it freezes .

The usecase is this.

A user uploads one or more files to our website. The service detects this and starts to process the files, sending a signal to the website when processing starts and when it ends.

The service checks for new files every 10 seconds. In this iteration we make a new connection to the server and stops it again, most of the time no messages is sent.

I suspect the connect/disconnect to be causing this. Is it better to open the connection when the services start and then use this connection in every iteration? The service must be able to run without restarts for months.

Comment: What is "some time" and what does freeze mean?

Comment: A couple of hours to a day or so. Freeze = hangs on connect. Right now i suspect it's the IIS's maximum connections of 10 on my development machine, but when I try to connect from another machine that is working.